# A Cleaner way, how to refactor async call

Tags: typescript, async-await, koa-router, class-validator

I have the following endpoint

```
  @Patch("/games/:id")
  @HttpCode(200)
  async updateGame(@Param("id") id: number, @Body() update: Partial<Game>) {
    const updatedGame = await Game.findOne(id);
    if (!updatedGame){
      throw new NotFoundError("HTTP 404 Not Found: No Games Here");
    }
    else if (update.color !== validColor(update.color)) {
      throw new BadRequestError("HTTP 400 Bad Request: No Such Color");
    } else if (update.board && moves(update.board, updatedGame.board) > 1) {
      throw new BadRequestError(
        "HTTP 400 Bad Request:  Only one move allowed. Wait your turn"
      );
    } else {
      console.log("Game has been updated");

      return Game.merge(updatedGame, update).save();
    }
  }
```

And I'm wondering if there is a 'cleaner' way for doing the same thing.
I.e how to refactor this using destructuring, shorthand etc..?

Comment: You could destructure `update` parameter (`{color, board}`). Also you can remove all `else` statements (no continuation once code is inside `if`). Also you'd better post this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com (check the help first)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I didn't know.
I will do so in the future.